# Catel 4.5.4 with Xamarin.Android - Error - System.NotSupportedException: Could not activate JNI Handle

Tags: xamarin.android, catel

I am trying to create a sample Xamarin.Android C# Application that uses Catel 4.5.4. 
It consists of an Activity, View Model class, and an Application class. (code at the end)

When I run it, I get the following error:

> 10-23 13:41:04.890 I/MonoDroid( 8769): System.NotSupportedException: Could not activate JNI Handle 0x6ec00025 (key_handle 0x41ed37d8) of Java type 'md5b251e24e9fff919bf177c55c6e30cd8e/MainActivity' as managed type 'Test.Views.MainActivity'. ---> System.NotSupportedException: To support navigation events in Android, Catel uses a custom ActivityLifecycleCallbacksListener. This requires an app instance though. Please make sure that the Android app contains an Application class.

**Full Debug Log:**
https://pastebin.com/UZHhVHfL

The error seems to be coming from this line in Catel source code:

https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/hotfix/4.5.4/src/Catel.MVVM/Catel.MVVM.Shared/MVVM/Navigation/NavigationAdapter.phone.android.cs#L210

```
    var activity = GetNavigationTarget<Activity>();
        var application = activity.Application;
        if (application == null)
        {
            const string error = "To support navigation events in Android, Catel uses a custom ActivityLifecycleCallbacksListener. This requires an app instance though. Please make sure that the Android app contains an Application class.";
            Log.Error(error);

            -->throw new NotSupportedException(error);
```

Here the activity.Application is null. How do I fix this?

---

I have tried the code with the following Catel versions:

4.1.0 - Code works

4.2.0 - Code works

4.5.0 - Code works

4.5.1 - Error

4.5.4 - Error

I have to use 4.5.4 because after fixing this, I want to port an existing WPF+Catel(4.5.4) Windows Application to Android.

---

Here is the relevant parts of the code:

**Views/MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
namespace Test.Views
{
    [Activity(Label = "Test", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Catel.Android.App.Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            Log.Debug("MainActivity", "Activity onCreate Called");
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

**MyApp.cs**

I created this class because of the error, but it didn't solve the problem. Should I add anything in the constructor? Or override any other function?

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;


namespace Test
{
    [Application(Debuggable = true, Label = "Test App")]
    class MyApp : Catel.Android.App.Application
    {

        public MyApp(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {

        }


        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            Log.Error("MyApp", "Application onCreate Called");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. We recommend to use catel 5.x, 4.x will not receive any new features and/or hotfixes. You could even go for Xamarin.Forms (which we are adding support for in 5.3 via .NET Standard 2.0).
2. Make sure to actually instantiate the application class *before* the activity. Then it should work.

Comment: I assumed that there's already an Application class instance because "Application onCreate Called" log message is being printed in Debug log. Should I create another instance manually? If so, where and how (what are the two parameters to the Catel Application class constructor)?